# Actionscript display text on screen once an action is performed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, display, dynamic-text

So I need to display a text once an action is performed but even though I tried to do so by using dynamic text and labels, I didn't manage to finish my programming due to errors:

```js
var group:RadioButtonGroup= new RadioButtonGroup ("Question1");
var group2:RadioButtonGroup= new RadioButtonGroup ("Question2");
var group3:RadioButtonGroup= new RadioButtonGroup ("Question3");
var group4:RadioButtonGroup= new RadioButtonGroup ("Question4");
var group5:RadioButtonGroup= new RadioButtonGroup ("Question5");
var counterT:int;
var counterF:int;

submit.buttonMode=true;
counterT=0;
counterF=0;

t1.group = group;
f1.group = group;

t2.group=group2;
f2.group=group2;

t3.group=group3;
f3.group=group3;

t4.group=group4;
f4.group=group4;

t5.group=group5;
f5.group=group5;

submit.label="Submit";
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,submitanswer); 

function submitanswer (event:MouseEvent): void {
    if (group.selection == t1)  {
        counterT==counterT+1
    }
    else 
    if (group.selection==f1) {
        counterF==counterF+1;
    }
}
if (group2.selection ==t2) {
    counterT==counterT+1
}
else
if (group2.selection==f2) {
    counterF==counterF+1
}
if (group3.selection ==t3) {
    counterT==counterT+1
}
else
if (group3.selection==f3) {
    counterF==counterF+1
}
if (group4.selection ==t4) {
    counterT==counterT+1
}       
else
if (group4.selection==f4) {
    counterF==counterF+1
}
if (group5.selection ==t5) {
    counterT==counterT+1
}       
else
if (group5.selection==f5) {
    counterF==counterF+1
}
```

Comment: please include the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you are using the `==` to set a value. You need to use `=` when setting values.  So like this:

```
if (x == y) {
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

or you can just use `counter++` like this

```
if (x == y) {
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that today
however right now I am trying to return the values and i get the error 1051 Return value must be undefined.
thus I can't print 

**if (group5.selection==f5) {
    counterF=counterF+1
  
   }
   return counterT;
   return counterF;


   }
  }
submit.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, submitanswer)

   txtField.text = " You've got " + counterT + " correct answers and " + counterF + " wrong answers";**

Comment: This is a different question than your original post, I think. If your first question is solved, mark it as correct.  Each post is to essentially be one question and one answer so that others with the same problem can come find the solution. If you are having a new problem, first see if a similar question has been asked. If not, post a new question.

Comment: well the text isn't printed when I click the submit button yet
no matter what actions i try
it's either printed before or not printed at all

Comment: Ok but what I'm saying is you don't have any code here that would cause anything to print, so this question can't be about printing. If you have a printing question, and there isn't a previous post that helps with your problem, ask a new question or clarify this one. You should not just keep updating a question with what ever your new problem is.

Comment: If you will post your updated code by editing your original post, I will take a look. Also please include where your code is written (in an .as file, or in frame 1 of the timeline, etc.) Trying to read code in a comment is too hard.

Comment: Thanks but some friends helped me to get out of it :) 
thanks for all your help as well!